# Can terminated licenses in EULAs be revived?

Tags: licensing, hacking, eula

If a user hacks their video game while the EULA of their video game says that the license will be terminated upon hacking, is it possible in any way to gain back the license once it's terminated or is the user permanently legally banned from playing that video game?

Answer (score 1):

A terminated agreement is over and done for all time.

The same people can always enter a new agreement on the same or different terms.

Comment: Does this mean that re-installing the video game and clicking the "I Agree" button on the violated EULA revives the license?